# how to pass scrapy.Response to the dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, response

I understand how to do this using the `requests` library

```
import requests

def start_requests(self):
        token = requests.get('https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/km/api/coveo/search/token').text
        headers = {
            ...
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {json.loads(token)["persistentSearchToken"]}',
            ...
        }
```

Tell me how to do this using `scrapy`?

At first I thought of doing this:

```
def start_requests(self):

       token = scrapy.Request(
            url='https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/km/api/coveo/search/token',
            callback=self.get_token
        )
       headers = {
                ...
                'Authorization': f'Bearer {json.loads(token)["persistentSearchToken"]}',
                ...
            }
def get_token(self, response):
        return response.text
```

But as it turned out, the "token" variable is not an object of the "Response"class. It is an object of the "Request" class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def start_requests(self):

   yield scrapy.Request(
        url='https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/km/api/coveo/search/token',
        callback=self.get_token,
   headers = {
            ...
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {json.loads(token)["persistentSearchToken"]}',
            ...
        })


def get_token(self, response):
    return response.text
```